# How to save exit code in history?

Tags: zsh, command-history

So with `setopt extended_history`, extra information is saved in the history file (format: `: <beginning time>:<elapsed seconds>;<command>`). The information is certainly useful, but I need more. I need to add the command's exit code to the history. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: This is not that trivial because the `zshaddhistory` function, which can be used to customize history saving, is executed *before* the command is run. Thus you can only get the exit status of the previous command.

Answer (score 3):

You could try https://github.com/larkery/zsh-histdb. To quote its Readme:

> It improves on the normal history by storing, for each history
> command:
>
> - The start and stop times of the command
> - The working directory where the command was run
> - The hostname of the machine
> - A unique per-host session ID, so history from several sessions is not confused
> - The exit status of the command

---

Update: Looks like this plugin hasn't seen updates since 2022. It might be that it's no longer maintained.